# Text wrapping in checklist items

Tags: lists, itemize, wrap

I am having some difficulty with text wrapping for items in a checklist I'm writing. Here is an image that illustrates the difficulty (see the second last checklist item):

[image: checklist1]

Would you have any suggestions for how to address this problem? It may be that the thing to look at first is the creation of the new command checklistAStart.

Example code follows:

```
\documentclass[american]{article}

% set page size and page margin
    \usepackage[a5paper, margin=1.5 mm]{geometry}
% tables
    % set table width
        \usepackage{tabularx}
    % tabularx alignment
        \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    % multi-spanned columns and rows in tables
        \usepackage{multirow}
% date
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[iso, inputamerican]{isodate}
% lists
    % description itemized list format
        \usepackage{enumitem}
% border around pages
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{pgfpages}
    \pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}{
         \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
    }{
        \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions{%
            logical pages=1,%
        }
        \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{
            border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
            border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
            resized width=.98\pgfphysicalwidth,%
            resized height=.98\pgfphysicalheight,%
            center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
        }%
    }
    \pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}

\begin{document}

\isodate

% tab
    \newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}

% commands for description itemised lists
    % commands for dimensions in description itemised lists
        % left position of item
            \newcommand{\leftMarginDistance}{8.5 cm}
        % #?
            \newcommand{\itemIndentDistance}{2 cm}
        % vertical separation
            \newcommand{\itemSeparationDistance}{-4 pt}
        % leftmost position of item denoter
            \newcommand{\labelIndentDistance}{0.2 cm}
    % commands for starting and ending description itemised lists
        \newcommand{
                \checklistAStart
            }
            {
                \begin{description}[
                    style=multiline,
                    itemsep=\itemSeparationDistance,
                    leftmargin=\leftMarginDistance,
                    itemindent=\itemIndentDistance,
                    labelindent=\labelIndentDistance,
                    font=\normalfont]
            }
        \newcommand{
                \checklistAEnd
            }
            {
                \end{description}
            }
    % commands for description itemised list items
        \newcommand{\checklistAitem}[2]{\item[#1 \dotfill]#2}
        \newcommand{\checklistAitemEmph}[2]{\item[\emph{#1}\dotfill]\emph{#2}}
        \newcommand{\checklistAtitle}[1]{\item[#1]}
        \newcommand{\checklistAsubitem}[2]{\item[\hspace{\labelIndentDistance}#1 \dotfill]#2}

% commands for titles
    % command for main titles
        \newcommand{\titleA}[1]{\noindent\large\textbf{#1}\normalsize\\}
    % command for subtitles
        \newcommand{\titleB}[1]{\noindent\textbf{#1}\normalsize}

% commands for headings
    % command for main headings
        \newcommand{\headingA}{
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabularx}{145 mm}{|lR|}
                    \hline
                    &\\
                    NORMAL AND EMERGENCY PROCEDURES CHECKLIST & MODEL \today-1\\
                    FOR CESSNA 172S INCLUDING G1000 AVIONICS&\\
                    &\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabularx}
            \end{center}}

\headingA

% left position of item
    \renewcommand{\leftMarginDistance}{6.5 cm}

\titleA{PRE-FLIGHT INSPECTION: INTERNAL}

\titleB{COCKPIT}

\checklistAStart
    \checklistAitem{aircraft position}{check obstructions}
    \checklistAitem{parking break}{set}
    \checklistAitem{control wheel lock}{remove and stow}
    \checklistAitem{ignition switch}{off, key removed}
    \checklistAitem{avionics switch (BUS 1 and BUS 2)}{off}
    \checklistAitem{static pressure alternate source value}{off}
    \checklistAitem{fuel selector}{both}
    \checklistAitem{fuel shutoff valve}{on (push fully in)}
    \checklistAitem{elevator trim}{check, set neutral (check full movement up and down)}
    \checklistAitem{master switch}{on}
\checklistAEnd

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use a `parbox` for the right hand side of the text:

```
\newcommand{\checklistAitem}[2]{\item[#1 \dotfill]\parbox[t]{5.50cm}{#2\unskip\strut}}
```

which yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- As per Barbara Beeton's suggestion I added a `\unskip\strut` to the end of the `\parbox`.

Comment: might want to use `...{#2\unskip\strut}}` at the end inside the `\parbox`.  otherwise, if the last continuation line has no descenders, it will be noticeably closer to the following item line.

Comment: Ah, this works very well! Thank you very much for your assistance.